# dotnet run and dotnet watch run sometimes takes over a minute to start on MacOS

Tags: .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I am not certain if it is limited to MacOS, I can only speak for it.

After developing for about half a day or so, starting up either `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch run` will sit and sit. It will take anywhere from 30 seconds to three minutes to finally start up my ASP.NET Web API application. Hitting Ctrl+c has it then sit and sit on exiting. Force stopping with a second Ctrl+c doesn't do anything.

A reboot typically resolves this problem for awhile. I looked and there aren't any rogue instances of `dotnet` running. Has anyone run into this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to share more details and code. This is not a MacOS issue. It is an issue with your machine and/or your code.

Comment: I doubt that it is a MacOS issue as well unless there is some bug with the dotnet implementation on MacOS... I'm not sure what kind of code to share. This happens across different ASP.NET projects and starts up at the same time